# Download the entire blockchain on Bitcoin cash in order to get your bitcoin cash coins?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-cash

Is it required to download the entire blockchain when using bitcoin cash client in order to send out bitcoin cash coins to an exchange?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically no, you only need to know your UTXOs so you can make a new transaction and sign that yourself. But if you want to use a Qt GUI or similar, then yes, it will attempt to download the entire blockchain again I would imagine.